# Calling Ethereum view functions from Polygon Smart contract?

Tags: solidity, oracles, polygon-bridge

Is there some sort of Polygon to Ethereum bridge product that allows you to write smart contracts which call view functions of smart contracts ddeployed on Ethereum Mainnet?

My smart contract looks at a number of ERC-721 contracts and performs a sort of "token inventory", of NFT contracts on both Ethereum and Polygon.

The "invesntory contract" is itself hosted on Polygon, but I'm wondering if there is a way to directly access a view function on E/thereum within a smart contract hosted on Polygon.

I am guessing I could write some kind of "oracle" that fetches from E/thereum but wondering if there is already a solution to this sort of issue I could leverage rather than developing something form scratch.

Comment: Don't have much experience on this but we have openzeppelin bridge.

Comment: If you have any further guidance, that would be helpful.  Does openzeppelin bridge somehow enable calling functions directly on ethereum from a polygon contract?

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge there is no way to do that directly from smart contract. I mean we barely have secure bridges for money that also takes up to 15 mins to transfer some tokens, which are not really transfer between blockchains, so i don't think this is possible. I think is possible to build something like this if you overenineer over Openzzepelin defender. Some santinels, some relayers, or some backend built from scratch...and there is your solution.